# Updating App Scopes To Include FulfillmentOrder Scopes

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have an app that is running on version 2022-04 (orders are being fulfilled through `Fulfillment` endpoints that got removed in version 2022-07) So I've Updated my code according to the documentation as version 2022-07 uses  `FulfillmentOrder` resource instead, that needs new scopes to be installed as well

```
'read_third_party_fulfillment_orders',
'write_third_party_fulfillment_orders',
'read_assigned_fulfillment_orders',
'write_assigned_fulfillment_orders'
```

As the documentation mentions no need to uninstall and reinstall the application to add the new scopes instead we can use

```
https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={nonce}&grant_options[]={access_mode}
```

but it always returns with a status code 403 (Forbidden) and an error message `Scope undefined for API access: oauth`

I've used both code and postman to trigger this request but the result was the same. Any help?

Comment: You can simplify your scope ask by removing the read_ since if you're granted write_, that gives you read_. Ensure you also include the original scopes too.

Answer (score 0):

if your app already have access to write_fulfillments scope then simply hit the post request

```
POST https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/request_granular_access_scopes.json
body - 
{
  "requested_scopes": [
    "write_assigned_fulfillment_orders"
  ]
}
```

for more info read this:

https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/fulfillment/migrate#step-4-temporarily-opt-out-of-fulfillment-orders-as-a-fulfillment-service-optional